# How to write Conditional Statement inside a Try Block in JAVA?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, try-catch

I am new to Java so please don't mind the syntax errors. I want to check if string1 OR string2 is null. If one of them is null then I want to throw a NullPointerException. Also, the return type of my method should be String.

```
public String handleException(Activity a) {
    try {
        if(a.string1.equals(null) || a.string2.equals(null))
            throw new NullPointerException();
    } 
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return "Null value found";
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Checking whether a reference typed variable is null must be done like `if (variable == null)`. Don't use `equals` here. 2) Why are you throwing an exception and directly catching it? That does not make any sense.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Having said which, if the aim is to throw a `NullPointerException`, calling `a.string1.equals(null)` will achieve the same result ;) (No, I'm not saying the code shouldn't be changed...)

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to decide whether you want to **throw** the exception (i.e. let code outside of that method handle it) or **catch** the exception (i.e. handle the method inside your method). While it is possible to do both in the same method (i.e. intentionally throw an exception and catch it within the same method), that's usually a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet Tricky to spot for a novice, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do that:

```
public String handleException(Activity a) {
    if(a.string1 == null || a.string2 == null) {
        // if string1 or string2 is null, throw your exception
        throw new NullPointerException("Null value found");
    }
    // do something now that you know your strings aren't null
    return "something";
}
```

To check if a string is null, you can just use `==`

Comment: This is most likely the result that is wanted ...

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to separate the error handling from the business logic:

```
public String handleException(Activity activity) {
    try {
        handleActivity(activity);
    } 
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return "Null value found";
    }
}

private void handleActivity(Activity activity) {
    // or some other logic that might cause a NullPointerException
    System.out.println(activity.string1.length());
    System.out.println(activity.string2.length());
}
```

But normally NPE's are not caught explicitly, we try to write code that doesn't cause them. There are several ways to check, like using [JSR 380](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation):

```
public class User {

    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;
```

You can also check yourself:

```
if (activity.string1 == null) {
    ...
```

In this case you should use `==` because `null` is not an Object (and cannot be [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) as an Object) and therefore cannot be evaluated by the `equals(Object)` method. Null is a special value (AKA [the billion dollar mistake](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare)) which indicates that a variable which is declared as an Object actually refers to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you don't even need a try-catch block for this operation
You could simply do

```
public String handleException(Activity a) {
    if(a.string1 == null || a.string2 == null){
            return "Null value found";
    }
    // return normal case value 
}
```

But from what I understood you just want to see how try-catch blocks work, so maybe you could explain more what you need exactly.

Comment: As it happens, NPEs should never be thrown, and *rarely* caught as they are normally indicative of a state of error in a program. They should be logged.